# Changing Android ContextMenu items while they are displayed (pre ICS)

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-contextmenu

I'm trying to set `ContextMenu` item invisible (`item.setVisible(false)`) while it is already displayed (saved reference to the menu as a member during `onCreateContextMenu()`).

While doing this on 2.3 I get exception:

`01-17 09:54:42.563: E/AndroidRuntime(2494): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908823, class com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView) with Adapter(class com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder$MenuAdapter)]`

All my code is ran in UI thread of course.

I guess that `ContextMenu` in 2.3 is implemented using `ListView` and blackened by corresponding `ListAdapterv.
In ICS this exception is not thrown and the item becomes invisible as I've planned.

Anybody has an Idea how to do it on 2.3?

One workaround is not to emulate `ContextMenu` via `Dialog`, but I'd rather stick to `ContextMenu`

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the Menu adapter by:

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

// ... Do Something

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
```

}

Comment: onContextItemSelected() is not yet called, the menu is displayed and then I'm trying to make one of the item disappear